# Difference with count result in Mongo group by query with Ruby/Javascript

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm using Mongoid to get a count of certain types of records in a Mongo database. When running the query with the javascript method:

```
db.tags.group({
    cond : { tag: {$ne:'donotwant'} },
    key: { tag: true },
    reduce: function(doc, out) { out.count += 1; },
    initial: { count: 0 }
});
```

I get the following results:

```
[
{"tag" : "thing", "count" : 4},
{"tag" : "something", "count" : 1},
{"tag" : "test", "count" : 1}
]
```

Does exactly what I want it to do. However, when I utilize the corresponding Mongoid code to perform the same query:

```
Tag.collection.group(
    :cond    => {:tag => {:$ne => 'donotwant'}},
    :key     => [:tag],
    :reduce  =>  "function(doc, out) { out.count += 1 }",
    :initial => { :count => 0 },
)
```

the count parameters are (seemingly) selected as floats instead of integers:

```
[
{"tag"=>"thing", "count"=>4.0},
{"tag"=>"something", "count"=>1.0},
{"tag"=>"test", "count"=>1.0}
]
```

Am I misunderstanding what's going on behind the scenes? Do I need to (can I?) cast those counts or is the javascript result just showing it without the .0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't distinguish between floats and ints. It has one Number type that is implemented as a double. So what you are seeing in Ruby is correct, the mongo shell output follows javascript printing conventions and displays Numbers that don't have a decimal component without the '.0'